# Gathering a distributed array using MPI

Tags: c, arrays, mpi, message-passing, collect

I have an array that is distributed across 3 processes in a cyclic fashion, let's say these are their parts:

```
Proc 0:
{0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2}
Proc 1:
{1.0, 1.0, 1.1, 1.1}
Proc 2:
{2.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.1}
```

I would like to gather all of these into one single array on one process like so:

```
{0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.1, 0.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.1, 2.1, 0.2}
```

i.e 2 elements from proc 0, then 2 from proc 1, 2 from proc 2, then over again with 2 from proc 0, 2 from proc 1, etc.

The final "block" may not be full. Like in the example, proc 0 has the last block with only 1 element instead of 2.

How could I go about solving this? I've looked at gather and gatherv, but I'm not sure how to use them when the data is distributed like this.

Edit: Got a suggestion to use the vector datatype, code looks like this

```
int disp[np], counts[np];

for(int i = 0; i < np; i++) {
    counts[i] = 1;
    disp[i] = i*blocksz;
}

MPI_Datatype distrib_arr;
MPI_Type_vector(num_blocks, blocksz, np*blocksz, MPI_DOUBLE, &distrib_arr);
MPI_Type_commit(&distrib_arr);

double *result = (double *) calloc (N, sizeof(double));

MPI_Gatherv(arr, arr_size, MPI_DOUBLE,
            result, counts, disp, distrib_arr,
            0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

And the result looks like this:

```
{0.0, 0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.1, 0.1, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.2}
```

i.e it seems to have collected the array from proc 0 correctly, but not the others? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use MPI_Gather. You can permute using datatype. Vector type may be appropriate here.

Comment: Is this for use with ScaLAPACK btw?

Comment: You can of course always use Send-Recv as a fallback, but it may perform worse.

Comment: I attempted using darray, but failed miserably :(. And no, it's not for use with ScaLAPACK. I use lapack for individual computations. Their results are what I would like to gather up into a single array as described.

Comment: Darray is awful. Use subarray or vector instead.

Comment: @Jeff I seem to be failing with vector too. I edited my post to include an example of what I tried. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Ok I'll try to solve it tomorrow.